# Select columns from a table with a space in its name

Tags: sql, select, alias, windev

I'm trying to select columns from two tables, `Lignes` and `Détail Production`. `Détail Production` links to the first one with the key `NoLigne` (which is the same name in both tables).

I know that I have to put `[ ]` or ``` `` ``` around the table's name, but I'm having the error `No value given for one or more required parameters`, which I believe means that SQL doesn't recognize the name. I tried aliasing the name of the table having a space in its name, but I have the same error. Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    NoProduction,
    Quantite,
    DateMaxProd,
    Lignes.Référence
FROM
    [Détail Production] AS D
INNER JOIN
    Lignes ON D.NoLigne = Lignes.NoLigne
WHERE
    D.Soldee = 0 AND 
    D.EtatLigne = 0 AND
    Lignes.Soldee = 0 AND
    (QteRecue - Quantite - Acompter * NbHS)>0
```

Unfortunately, I can't get rid of the alias or the name of the table in the FROM and WHERE clause because my tables share columns with the same name. I can't rename the tables or the columns, and I'm actually using the software Windev which uses HFSQL as a dbms. I'm trying to connect to an access database with the OLEDB connector, and when I switch to HFSQL it works.

Here is a mre:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  [Détail Production]
  INNER JOIN
  Lignes ON [Détail Production].NoLigne = Lignes.NoLigne
```

When using HFSQL database, it works, when using OLEDB with an access database, it throws the error `No value given for one or more required parameter`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? ANSI/ISO SQL has double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"Detail Production"`.

Comment: I'm using HFSQL, when using double quotes I get the error `incomplete request clause`

Comment: `AND (QteRecue - Quantite - Acompter * NbHS)` is missing something.

Comment: Correct, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

```
SELECT
    D.NoProduction,
    D.Quantite,
    D.DateMaxProd,
    Lignes.Référence
FROM
    [Détail Production] AS D
INNER JOIN
    Lignes ON D.NoLigne = Lignes.NoLigne
WHERE
    D.Soldee = 0 AND 
    D.EtatLigne = 0 AND
    Lignes.Soldee = 0 AND
    (D.QteRecue - D.Quantite - D.Acompter * D.NbHS) > 0
```

I was missing the comparison on the last condition of the WHERE clause. I thought it was because of the alias or the brackets because others online had similar problems and the error changed as I tried other ways of writing the FROM clause. The right way to write a name with spaces in HFSQL is with brackets [ ]. Also, there were problems with names not matching accents from the database.